# change the button style in android code programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

i wish to change the button background color,textcolor,text size using android code programmatically.

```
   Button btnLoadMore = new Button(this);
    btnLoadMore.setText("Load More");

    // Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
    lv.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);
```

In this above code succesfully set the Load More Text.but i have to wrote below line

```
btnLoadMore.setTextColor("#FF1493");
```

means am getting following error

```
The method setTextColor(int) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments
```

(String)

How can i resolve this error.please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4602929/1405983

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148450/textwatchereditable-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-from-learning-android)

Comment: thanks for giving such a nice idea....i have to change the background using below line:btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lgnbttn);

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Check this link: [How to set the text color of TextView in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-text-color-of-textview-by-coding)

Comment: i have to change the background using below line:btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lgnbttn);             it is successfully worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Color.ParseColor("color hex value");
```